# How to copy directory structure, by only two levels but not the third?

Tags: windows-xp, xcopy

From XP's Command Prompt, I am using XCOPY to copy directory structure of s:\bloo\"[8family]\"[30-40genus]\"[5species]\ and want to limit the structure to just the genus and families, and ignore the species. However, looking through the options for XCOPY none seem on the face to apply to this.

Is there a switch I should be using to limit this? If not, is there a nice batch delete function that I can use to trim the [species] directories from the [genus] directories? (note: corporate lock-down, cannot install applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the hard-to-find [XP026 build of Robocopy](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1887376/ROBOCOPY.EXE), which fixes some bugs from the build from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit.  This version still works on XP/2003.

An alternative to Robocopy is [**Xxcopy**](http://www.xxcopy.com/).  There is a free 32-bit version and it has so many options you will not believe it.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have admin rights over the computer and would be unable to install it, though based on the 300+ switches I'm guessing one would mimic the `/lev:n` option

Comment: @mfg: I have updated my answer to include Robocopy XP026, which does not need admin rights to install, as it is just a standalone .exe.  Just drop it into any directory in your PATH, for easiest use.

Comment: bang! your robocopy s:\bloo s:\blah /e /lev:3 did what I needed, and portable at that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not with `xcopy`, but take a look at `robocopy`:

- http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

It has the `/LEV:n` option.

Comment: Wow, now that is a list of options. Unfortunately I'm running this on an XP machine and robocopy is Win7... maybe in the future it will be backported

Comment: It is available for XP: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd (don't be fooled by the title, look at supported OSes near the bottom).

Comment: Good to know there's a module for it; unfortunately I would still need admin rights to install the module.

Comment: Yes, for the above definitively. Check here for a standalone versions: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3767351.php.

Comment: Thanks for the help, saved me purging a ton of stuff, or typing out a bajillion directories

Comment: No prob, glad to help!